# Lining up spatial references in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

[image: Delta projection problem]

The PCS and the GCS for the shapefiles, the DEM below the polygon file and the data frame are all the same. But the coordinates are completely off. When I bring newly downloaded data onto the map it lines up with the coordinates you see in the lower corner of the screen. I can't get everything else to line up.

I've tried reprojecting everything, changing Geoprocessing Environments, defining projection etc.

Could the  data be corrupted?

Should I just redownload everything from the start?

Comment: Your new data is it a different coordinate system to all the existing data? Typically you need to set the _Transformation_ of a coordinate system when you are mixing layers with different coordinate systems, you do not mention this in the things you have done?

Comment: What are the coordinates (put them into a new ArcMap by themselves) of the layers that aren't lining up?

Comment: Yeah, I did do that transformation. I think the problem is, I had everything in a geodatabase, and I was frequently changing around PCS and GCS settings as I was adding a mosaic DEM to the data frame. I do believe I corrupted the data so it was impossible to project it properly: I couldn't even export the feature classes to shapefiles in order to reconfigure the .prj files. At the end of the day I just deleted everything that didn't fit and re downloaded (and in one tragic case, re created) all the data. Everything projected on the fly and now it's all working right.